# Kivy: Control + Backspace in TextInput to delete token

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to get my TextInput boxes to recognize a ctrl+backspace keystroke to backspace an entire token (like most modern programs).

So far, I have this:

```py
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        """Run when a key is pressed down"""
        # Do backspace for single and ctrl+backspace for token
        if keycode[1] == 'backspace':
            if 'control' in modifiers:
                pass # Delete previous token

        return super(TabTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
```

I'm not sure how to detect the previous token from the cursor and delete it without interfering with the existing behavior of the `do_backspace()` method.

Fyi, I am still using Kivy 1.11.1 and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
    """Run when a key is pressed down"""
    # Do backspace for single and ctrl+backspace for token
    if keycode[1] == 'backspace':
        if 'ctrl' in modifiers:
            done = False
            while not done:
                self.do_backspace()
                cc, cr = self.cursor
                line = self._lines[cr]
                if cc == 0 or line[cc-1] == ' ':
                    done = True
            return True

    return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! 
I replaced the condition `line[cc-1] == ' '` with `line[cc-1] in ' .-'` to fit my use case better, but that's just nitpicking.